# Implementing primary key agnostic Room object equivalence

Tags: kotlin, android-room, equals

Consider the following simple `data class` being used as a Room `@Entity`

```kotlin
@Entity
data class SimpleDataClass(
    val name: String,
    val timestamp: String,
    val isInvalid: Boolean = false,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id:Int=0
)
```

The functionality I am trying to implement is that two `SimpleDataClass` objects should be considered same if all there properties are same *regardless of* their `id` (which is only added to the class structure because it's going to be stored in a database). Eg. the timestamp only stores the dayOfMonth and the user did the same thing over many months

Note that as database records, they should be considered separate since the user really did generate two records hence their different auto incremented primary keys.

One can do this by writing explicit `equals` that ignores `id` comparison. But then one also needs to write other comparison functions like `hashCode`, `toString` etc. which I am trying to avoid (let the compiler generate them)

To let the compiler ignore `id` , I followed the advise [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#properties-declared-in-the-class-body)

```kotlin
@Entity
data class SimpleDataClass(
    val name: String,
    val timestamp: String,
    val isInvalid: Boolean = false,
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int=0
}
```

Note that `id` is now a `var` to allow for its setter

This achieves what I was looking for except that it breaks copying. When a record read from the database as a `SimpleDataClass` object is copied (via `simpleDataClass.copy()`), its `id` isn't transferred to the copy. To remedy that I am using

```kotlin
old.copy(/*change some params, or not*/).also { it.id = old.id}
```

Neither method feels satisfactory. **How to achieve this?**